# jQuery: Sort children according to their types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I am in great trouble dealing with my code. I am redesigning the look so, there are new things to do. Basically, I have a parent element with few children elements of two types and I want to sort so, `p` tags are on top and `div` tag is at last:

```
<div id="parent">
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div id="parent">
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd better sort it before DOM insertion imo.

Comment: @Jonathan No man it is upto the user, I can only do it later.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing is moving `div` elements to the end of the parent, you don't really need to sort. Just detach the `div` elements from the DOM, then append them to the parent.

```
$('#parent div').detach().appendTo('#parent');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d7j2w/)

Comment: Yeah! nice. I had only 1 div :P